# Unable to deploy of Heroku because of Python Package with Error

Tags: django, github, heroku, csv-import

I'm trying to upload my django application on Heroku. It works on local because I corrected the error, but for some reason after I added whitenoise to get local files so that I can deploy on Heroku, it keeps bringing up the same error. 
I am loading a local package csv-imports and it has an error on line 70.

```
class ImportModel(models.Model):
    """ Optional one to one mapper of import file to Model """
    #this is the line with the error and I fixed it here with the on_delete
    csvimport = models.ForeignKey(CSVImport, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    numeric_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    natural_key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

However when I run:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following error which I have fixed on my local, but seems to keep coming up with Heroku. The file has been changed. I might not be on the right file path given by Heroku there is no app/.heroku/ on my computer. But, there is only one installation of csv-imports on my computer and that one has been fixed as above. Why do I keep getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/csvimport/models.py", line 72, in ImportModel
remote:            csvimport = models.ForeignKey(CSVImport)
remote:        TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
emote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to gentle-lowlands-98196.
remote:
```

Comment: I think you're getting that error because you need to push your changes to your repo first.

Comment: Are you sure that you committed your changes to git before pushing?

Comment: The problem is that this cvs-import is in a different folder it's in lib/python3.7/site-packages/csv-import, while my project is in src/djanopractice/myproject. I am pushing form myproject folder. Do I need to push from src?

Comment: @ Sam, I'm pretty sure that I fixed this error days ago on local and created the git repository today.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your static directory, first you have to run:
"python manage.py collectstatic"
This will give you the path of your static directory or an exception like you are using STATIC_URL without STATIC_ROOT Directory.